# How can I connect Android to Arduino MKR1000 over TCP/IP protocol?

Tags: android, tcp, wifi, socketexception, arduino-mkr1000

I am developing an Android app to control an Arduino MKR1000 board, by communicating over the TCP/IP networking protocol. The Arduino works as an Access Point and send data, when there is a client available. My Android app manage to connect to Arduino's WiFi shield, but I have an issue with implementing the TCP client, on Android side. In fact, when I try to connect the Socket on the specified port number, on the named host, I get a Socket Exception.

I have already seen some answers:

[java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed, with java.net.SocketException: Connection reset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6772215/7262578)

[Official reasons for "Software caused connection abort: socket write error"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2126607/7262578)

[java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: connect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2059543/7262578)

But I haven't been able to figure out how to solve this.

Socket Exception:

```
W/System.err:       java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort
W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:334)
W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
W/System.err:     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:586)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:535)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:427)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:243)
W/System.err:     at com.progetto.xxxxx.arduino.MyIntentService.onHandleIntent(MyIntentService.java:69)
W/System.err:     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:67)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
W/System.err:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Android code:

TCP client

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {

Socket mSocket = null;
public static final int PORT = 2390;

InetAddress local = null;

public MyIntentService() {
    super("MyIntentService");
}


@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

            try {

               local = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.7");

                mSocket=new Socket(local,PORT); // Exception occurs 
                Log.i(TAG, "socket");

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "UNknownHost");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i(TAG, "IOEXCeption");
            }
        }

}
```

Main Activity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {


    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

      final String action = intent.getAction();


        if(action.equals(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)) 
         {
            WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
            if (wifiInfo!=null) 
             {
                String ssidN = wifiInfo.getSSID();
                NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
                boolean connected = info.isConnected();
                if (connected) 
                     {
                    if (ssidN.contains(ssid)) 
                          {

                        startService(intents);

                           }
                       }
                  }
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifiManager.disconnect();
     wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
    intents=new Intent(this,MyIntentService.class);

    intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
}


public void WifiAp(){

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater=getLayoutInflater();
    view_pass=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.wifi_item,null);
    Log.i(TAG, "view");

    txt_annulla=(TextView)view_pass.findViewById(R.id.txt_annulla);
    txt_connetti=(TextView)view_pass.findViewById(R.id.txt_connetti);

    final android.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialog.setView(view_pass);
    final android.app.AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    dialog.show();
    txt_annulla.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    txt_connetti.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            wifiManager.disconnect();
            WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();

            conf.SSID = "\"" + ssid + "\"";

            conf.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
            conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
            int newNetworkId = wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);

            //Adds to the list of network and returns the network id which can be used to enable it later.
            List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
            for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
                if (i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + ssid + "\"")) {
                    wifiManager.disconnect();
                    wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
                    wifiManager.reconnect();

                    break;
                }
            }

            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.power:

            WifiAp();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,intentFilter);

}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);

}
```

}

Arduino code:

```
#include <SPI.h> 
#include <WiFi101.h> 

#include <Arduino.h>

char apssid[] = "WifiMkr"; 

IPAddress ipC(192, 168, 1, 7);     
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS; 

unsigned int localport = 2390;   
//IPAddress remoteIp;
unsigned long timeM=0;

WiFiServer server(localport);

WiFiClient client;
IPAddress ip;  
unsigned long tsample=1;

 void setup() { 
   Serial.begin(9600); 


while (!Serial) {
  //   wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
}

   Serial.println("Access Point"); 

   if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) 
   { 
     Serial.println("WiFi shield non è presente"); 

   } 

 WiFi.config(ipC);


  Serial.println("Creating access point named: "); 


 Serial.println(apssid); 

  if (WiFi.beginAP(apssid) != WL_AP_LISTENING) { 
   Serial.println("Creating access point failed"); 

  }else{
    Serial.println("Creating access point success"); 
    } 


   delay(1000);

      server.begin();

  printWiFiStatus();   

  // compare the previous status to the current status
    Serial.println("\nStarting connection to server...");

 }

  void loop() {
  unsigned long time=millis();


 if (status != WiFi.status()) {
     //it has changed update the variable
    status = WiFi.status();
     if (status == WL_AP_CONNECTED) 
     {
      byte remoteMac[6];


      // a device has connected to the AP
      Serial.print("Device connected to AP, MAC address: ");
      WiFi.APClientMacAddress(remoteMac);
      Serial.print(remoteMac[5], HEX);
      Serial.print(":");
      Serial.print(remoteMac[4], HEX);
      Serial.print(":");
      Serial.print(remoteMac[3], HEX);
      Serial.print(":");
      Serial.print(remoteMac[2], HEX);
      Serial.print(":");
      Serial.print(remoteMac[1], HEX);
      Serial.print(":");
      Serial.println(remoteMac[0], HEX);  
    }
    else 
    {
      // a device has disconnected from the AP, and we are back in listening mode

      Serial.println("Device disconnected from AP"); 
    }
 }
 client= server.available();
 if(client){
  Serial.println("hello client");
  while(client.connected()){
   //
        int value = analogRead(A3);
  client.write(value);
  Serial.println("millis");
  Serial.println(tsample);
  Serial.println(millis());
  Serial.println(timeM);
  while(millis()<timeM+tsample);
        }
 }

 }

void printWiFiStatus() {
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print your WiFi shield's IP address:
   ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  // print the received signal strength:
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");
  // print where to go in a browser:
  Serial.print("To see this page in action, open a browser to http://");
  Serial.println(ip);

}
```